# Default search will display multiple search results for the same data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, search, search-results

I have a team site which contains some announcement Apps, document management Apps etc. now let say I search for a sentence , then SharePoint will display the the search results from the following components:-

1. The  announcement item that contains the sentence .
2. The announcement list , which contain the associated announcement item
3. The announcement App part, which contain the associated  announcement item.

So is there  a way to force the search to only display the item which contains the search criteria , without the need to display the list or the App part that contain the associated item?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the crawl in Central Administration. Create Crawl rules to exclude certain results. For example, you can exclude the "All items" list views by creating a crawl rule with the setting:

```
://*/AllItems.aspx
```

Fine tuning search results is a never-ending process. Whenever you find a page that you don't want to be returned in the search results, create a crawl rule to exclude that page. If it is a page like AllItems.aspx, use the wildcards to exclude the view for all lists and libraries.